# ggplot visual of convex hull - shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, convex-hull

I want to create a ggplot visual of convex hull for any numeric variables the user provides while allowing the hull to split into several hulls for a chosen categorical input variable.

Something like this in shiny where users can pick as many x variables as they want

```
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

df<- iris
str(df)

b <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width, y = Petal.Width))
 
# Convex hull of groups
b + geom_point(aes(color = Species, shape = Species)) +
  stat_chull(aes(color = Species, fill = Species), 
             alpha = 0.1, geom = "polygon") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))
```

Here is my shiny code so far, which, needless to say does not work.Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
df<- mtcars
numeric_cols <- df %>% select(where(is.numeric))
categorical_cols <- df %>% select(where(is.factor))
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("MTCARS"),
  selectInput("Columns","Numeric Columns",
              names(numeric_cols), multiple = TRUE),
  selectInput("Columns","Categorical Columns",
              names(categorical_cols), multiple = TRUE),
  plotOutput("myplot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  Dataframe2 <- reactive({
    mtcars[,input$Columns] 
  })
  
  my_plot<- reactive({ggplot(Dataframe2(), aes(mpg, cyl))+geom_point()})
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    my_plot()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 issues here. First, you have zero categorical variables in `mtcars`. Second, you should use unique `ID`s, but you are using same IDs for both `selectInputs`.  Lastly, for the plot you need to use the selected columns, and not specify `mpg` and `cyl`.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
df<- mtcars
numeric_cols <- df %>% dplyr::select(where(is.numeric))
categorical_cols <- df %>% dplyr::select(where(is.factor))
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("MTCARS"),
  selectInput("Columns","Numeric Columns",
              names(numeric_cols), multiple = TRUE),
  # selectInput("Columns","Categorical Columns",
  #             names(categorical_cols), multiple = TRUE),
  plotOutput("myplot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  Dataframe2 <- reactive({
    req(length(input$Columns)>=2)
    mtcars[,input$Columns] 
  })
  
  my_plot<- reactive({ggplot(Dataframe2(), aes(.data[[input$Columns[1]]],.data[[input$Columns[2]]] ))+geom_point()})
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    my_plot()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```